# Wordpress: Edited siteurl in database, reverted, but now get server errors

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I updated a clients Wordpress to 3.5.2 but couldn't login via wp-admin. The site is within another directory within public_html, eg: `public_html/site` so I thought that this might be causing the errors

I logged on to PHPMyAdmin, went to the wp_options table and saw that the siteurl seemed to be correct, eg: `mysite.com/site/`. Trying to see if it would help, I changed it to just `mysite.com/` but that broke everything - I could even access the front page any more, I got a Server 500 error.

So I changed siteurl back to `mysite.com/site/` again. However, my browser still shows the 500 error. Cleared cache to no affect.

Im not sure what else I can do. I changed the siteurl row back to what it was originally but the site remains broke. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "relocating" the site by putting the original URLs in define statements in wp-config.php. See See [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for that and other recovery instructions.

I don't know why changing the URL would cause 500 errors. Check the .htaccess file, too; but that doesn't get written to when working in the database.

Comment: Thanks, .htaccess was ok but adding the define statements worked!